# shouldn't ping time be the sum of trace route hops time?

Tags: networking, tcp

just the difference between them is confusing me...

Comment: Hello, welcome to Super User. Your question has been migrated here, where it is more adapted. To regain ownership over your question, you should create an account here, and associate it with your Stack Overflow account in user options.

Answer (score 2):

No because the trace route time is to that hop and back again. So if you add them all up it would be You -> Hop 1 -> You -> Hop 2 -> You etc which is not how you get from You -> other PC.

Comment: Should be You -> other PC -> You, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between who?

Aside the hard-to-inderstand question, the thing is: ping measures the time taken by a 32bit packet to do a **round trip**. The TTL is just the final value after the hops...

Check this by tracert in windows or traceroute in unix. Will see avg max and min time for each hop...

Answer (score 0):

Also, often intermediate routers (internet backbone routers and such) are configured to not respond to ICMP (ping) packets, which is why trace route times out on several of the hops for traces across the internet.  So summing the hop times is not possible when any intermediate router refuses to respond to ICMP.

Answer (score 0):

if the trace to host xyz.com passes by A, B, C hosts, then the ping packet should go 4 hops from your computer to reach the destination, on the other hand, one tracert roundtrip time of one hop is the time from your computer to that specific host

Answer (score 0):

When you do a traceroute, you are actually sending several packets, with incremental TTL (time to live).

First packet will hit the first "hop", and come back, you will get the ping time to this place. Same for second packet, which will stop after the second "hop", and so on. Each "ping" you get in a traceroute is the time to each intermediate router, from you, and not the time between two routers.

In traceroute, only the final packet, the one which reached the destination and came back, is the actual ping from you to this place.

You can find further details on how traceroute works, on the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute).